Error Loading Gazebo Plugin: gz_ros2_control/GazeboSimSystem Class Not Found
I'm encountering an issue while trying to load a Gazebo simulation for my robot in ROS 2. After receiving the robot description from the appropriate topic, I get the following error messages in the terminal:

Terminal Snippet
Context:
I'm using ROS 2 Jazzy and the gz_ros2_control plugin.
My configuration files and plugin specifications seem to be set up correctly, but I keep encountering this error regarding the gz_ros2_control/GazeboSimSystem class not being found.
I have verified that the plugin library (libgz_ros2_control-system.so) is present in the /opt/ros/jazzy/lib directory.
Questions:
What could be causing the gz_ros2_control/GazeboSimSystem class to not be recognized?
Are there any specific dependencies or configurations I need to check to resolve this issue?
How can I ensure that the correct Gazebo plugin is loaded for my ROS 2 setup?
My gazebo.xacro file
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<robot name="bumperbot" xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">
    <gazebo reference="wheel_right_link">
        <mu1>100000000000000.0</mu1>
        <mu2>100000000000000.0</mu2>
        <kp>1000000000000.0</kp>
        <kd>10.0</kd>
        <minDepth>0.001</minDepth>
        <maxVel>0.1</maxVel>
        <fdir>1 0 0</fdir>
    </gazebo>

    <gazebo reference="wheel_left_link">
        <mu1>100000000000000.0</mu1>
        <mu2>100000000000000.0</mu2>
        <kp>1000000000000.0</kp>
        <kd>10.0</kd>
        <minDepth>0.001</minDepth>
        <maxVel>0.1</maxVel>
        <fdir>1 0 0</fdir>
    </gazebo>

    <gazebo reference="caster_front_link">
        <mu1>0.1</mu1>
        <mu2>0.1</mu2>
        <kp>1000000.0</kp>
        <kd>100.0</kd>
        <minDepth>0.001</minDepth>
        <maxVel>0.1</maxVel>
    </gazebo>

    <gazebo reference="caster_rear_link">
        <mu1>0.1</mu1>
        <mu2>0.1</mu2>
        <kp>1000000.0</kp>
        <kd>100.0</kd>
        <minDepth>0.001</minDepth>
        <maxVel>0.1</maxVel>
    </gazebo>

    <gazebo>
        <!-- <xacro:if value="$(arg is_ignition)">
        <plugin filename="ign_ros2_control-system"
            name="ign_ros2_control::IgnitionROS2ControlPlugin">
            <parameters>
                $(find bumperbot_controller)/config/bumperbot_controllers.yaml
                </parameters>
            </plugin>
        </xacro:if> -->

        <!-- <xacro:unless value="$(arg is_ignition)"> -->
    <plugin filename="gz_ros2_control-system"
        name="gz_ros2_control::GazeboSimROS2ControlPlugin">
        <parameters>$(find bumperbot_controller)/config/bumperbot_controllers.yaml</parameters>
        </plugin>


        <!-- </xacro:unless> -->
    </gazebo>

</robot>
```


How have you installed gz_ros2_control? I see ign_ros2_control in your terminal, which comes from a humble installation.
Do the gz_ros2_control_demos work for you?

@ChristophFroehlich I have gz_ros2_control installed,  the demos work without issues.

why do you load both plugins, ign and gz, in the URDF? the xacro:if/unless is commented out.

@ChristophFroehlich The only package i am including is gz_ros_control. the ign plug is commented out and the if/unless. the initial intention was to load the plugins based on the version of ros on the system.  ros humble uses ignition plugin in. whereas jazzy uses gz_ros. After having  the error message about the plugins, I commented out the if/unless and just added gz_ros_control directly  incase the if/unless was not working properly.
